# where is ".class" declared in java?

Tags: java

I just noticed that I can create any class (let's say MyClass) and do a

```
Class a = MyClass.class
```

MyClass only extends from Object class, but I checked the documentation of Object class, but could not find a field named "`class`". Where is this field comming from?

Comment: Its a literal, used as - the type of String.class is Class<String>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a "class literal" and it's formally defined in [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) of the Java language specification:

> A *class literal* is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a '.' and the token `class`.

It is an expression, the `class` keyword does not represent a type member.